# Using endpoint with .AspNet.ApplicationCookie

Tags: asp.net, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I'm trying to use an endpoint that is authenticated with what I think is a MSAL token. I am an authorized user of this endpoint and have authorized credentials but cannot seem to get a token to use the endpoint.

I have tried using the documented workflow in python of requesting a MSAL token for use but I ran into an issue where I think my endpoint is set not to allow public clients How would I go around that if possible. The python library I used was the `PublicClientApplication` from `msal`.

I have several means of authentication including the `Tenant-Id`, `Client-Id`, `authority`, `username`, and `password` but I can't seem to get an authorized token I'm unsure of what I'm doing wrong.

I willing to change languages if it would make it easier on me I just trying to access this endpoint without making any changes to Azure AD. If you have any questions leave a comment and I will get back to it in at most 48 hours.

Concluding I'm trying to access an endpoint that requires a .AspNet.ApplicationCookie if you have any ideas or work arounds PLEASE give me a heads up.

Thanks

Comment: please let us know which flow you are using for MSAL and also how you are making a token request.

Comment: The python library I used was the PublicClientApplication from msal I tried both device code and usernamepassword. Which resulted in an error